# KeyError for key that exists in dictionary

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that has an array that loops through an array of keys for a dictionary. It gets each of these keys, applies it to the dictionary and then gets the returned value and uses it for spacing out my unicode table. Example:

```py
sizeDict = {
    "Name": 16,
    "Mobile": 11,
    "Pizza": 7,
    "Drink": 7,
    "Dessert": 7,
    "Total": 7
}
header = ['name', 'mobile', 'pizza', 'drink', 'dessert', 'total']


def printRow(firstChar, endChar, space, specialChar, spaceArray, spaceDict):
    output = firstChar
    for i in range(0, len(spaceArray)):
        if(i == len(spaceArray) - 1):
            specialChar = endChar
        output = output + space * spaceDict[spaceArray[i].title()] + specialChar
    return output


print(printRow("┏", "┓", "━", "┳", header, sizeDict))
#Returns ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┓
```

The problem for some reason, is that it doesn't recognise some of the values from the array as actual keys in the dictionary, even though both strings are exactly alike. Here is the specific array, dictionary and error message where the error occured.

```py
statHeader = ['Average Total', 'Earned', '% of Total']
statSizeDict = {
    "Average Total": 15,
    "Earned": 10,
    "% of Total": 20
}
statSizeArray = [15,10,20]
"""
<ipython-input-3-5c5f25401e4d> in statOrders(statData)
    272         for i in range(0, len(statHeader)):
    273             tempString += spaceVal(statHeader[i], statSizeDict[statHeader[i]])
--> 274         print(printRow("┏", "┓", "━", "┳", statHeader, statSizeDict))
    275         print(tempString)
    276         print(printRow("┣", "┫", "━", "╋", statHeader, statSizeDict))

<ipython-input-3-5c5f25401e4d> in printRow(firstChar, endChar, space, specialChar, spaceArray, spaceDict)
     51         if(i == len(spaceArray) - 1):
     52             specialChar = endChar
---> 53         output = output + space * spaceDict[spaceArray[i].title()] + specialChar
     54     return output
     55 # ========================================================================================================================== #

KeyError: '% Of Total'
"""
```

Here is the complete code for reference:

```py
import csv
import os
# ========================================================================================================================== #
data = []
testData = [8001, 499382, 'int', 'int', 'float']
header = ['name', 'mobile', 'pizza', 'drink', 'dessert', 'total']
statHeader = ['Average Total', 'Earned', '% of Total']
# ========================================================================================================================== #
orderDict = {
    "Small cheese pizza": ['pizza', 5],
    "Big cheese pizza": ['pizza', 10],
    "Small drink": ['drink', 1],
    "Large drink": ['drink', 1.5],
    "Small dessert": ['dessert', 0.5],
    "Large dessert": ['dessert', 1]
}
posDict = {
    "Pizza Total": 2,
    "Drink Total": 3,
    "Dessert Total": 4
}
returnDict = {
    1: 'Task completed succesfully.',
    2: 'Task encountered an unexpected error.',
    3: 'No file data was found.',
    4: 'Value does not exist or is out of range.',
    5: 'Value type is invalid or does not exist in current range.',
    6: 'Value length was to large for function.'
}
sizeDict = {
    "Name": 16,
    "Mobile": 11,
    "Pizza": 7,
    "Drink": 7,
    "Dessert": 7,
    "Total": 7
}
statSizeDict = {
    "Average Total": 15,
    "Earned": 10,
    "% of Total": 20
}
statSizeArray = [15,10,20]


def spaceVal(value, size):
    return str(value)[:size] + " " * (size-len(str(value))) + '┃'


def printRow(firstChar, endChar, space, specialChar, spaceArray, spaceDict):
    output = firstChar
    for i in range(0, len(spaceArray)):
        if(i == len(spaceArray) - 1):
            specialChar = endChar
        output = output + space * spaceDict[spaceArray[i].title()] + specialChar
    return output
# ========================================================================================================================== #


def newOrderCash(appendData, name, mobile, pizza=0, drink=0, dessert=0):
    """
    Appends the formatted order to the data list and returns
    the name of the customer and the total of their order.

    Args:

        appendData - a list which has the order
        appended to the end of it.
        name - a string value containing the customer's name.
        mobile - a string or integer value which contains
        the mobile number of the person making the order.
        pizza - the total cost of the ordered pizza which
        defaults to zero if no pizza was ordered.
        drink - the total cost of the ordered pizza which
        defaults to zero if no pizza was ordered.
        dessert - the total cost of the ordered pizza which
        defaults to zero if no pizza was ordered.

    Returns:
        A list containing the name of the customer and the
        total cost of their order.
        None - If name or mobile is not provided.
    """
    if(name is None or name == "" or mobile is None or mobile == ""):
        return None
    if(len(name) > 21 or len(str(mobile)) > 10):
        return 6
    total = float(pizza) + float(drink) + float(dessert)
    appendData.append([name, str(mobile), float(pizza), float(drink), float(dessert), total])
    returnData = name, total
    return list(returnData)


def newOrderItems(appendData, name, mobile, items):
    """
    Appends the formatted order to the data list and returns
    the name of the customer and the total of their order.

    Args:

        appendData - a list which has the order
        appended to the end of it.
        name - a string value containing the customer's name.
        mobile - a string or integer value which contains
        the mobile number of the person making the order.
        items - a list which contains the items the
        customer has ordered.

    Returns:
        A list containing the name of the customer and the
        total cost of their order.
        None - If name or mobile is not provided.
    """
    if(name is None or name == "" or mobile is None or mobile == ""):
        return None
    total = 0
    drink = 0
    dessert = 0
    pizza = 0
    for i in items:
        total += float(orderDict[i][1])
        if(orderDict[i][0] == 'pizza'):
            pizza += float(orderDict[i][1])
        elif(orderDict[i][0] == 'drink'):
            drink += float(orderDict[i][1])
        elif(orderDict[i][0] == 'dessert'):
            dessert += float(orderDict[i][1])
    tempArray = name, str(mobile), pizza, drink, dessert, total
    appendData.append(list(tempArray))
    returnData = name, total
    return list(returnData)


def newBulkOrders(appendData, names, mobiles, items):
    """
    Appends the formatted order to the data list and returns
    the names of the customer and the totals of their order.

    Args:

        appendData - a list which has the order
        appended to the end of it.
        name - a list containing the customers' names.
        mobiles - a list containing the customers' mobiles.
        items - a list of lists containing.

    Returns:
        A list containing the names of the customers
        and the totals of their orders.
        None - If name or mobile is not provided.
        Task Code 4 - If a type error occurs.
    """
    if(names is None or names == "" or mobiles is None or mobiles == ""):
        return None
    try:
        returnTotals = []
        returnNames = []
        errorArray = []
        returnList = []
        for l in range(0, len(names)):
            total = 0
            drink = 0
            dessert = 0
            pizza = 0
            tempItems = items[l]
            for i in tempItems:
                total += float(orderDict[i][1])
                if(orderDict[i][0] == 'pizza'):
                    pizza += float(orderDict[i][1])
                elif(orderDict[i][0] == 'drink'):
                    drink += float(orderDict[i][1])
                elif(orderDict[i][0] == 'dessert'):
                    dessert += float(orderDict[i][1])
            tempArray = names[l], str(mobiles[l]), float(pizza), drink, dessert, total
            returnTotals.append(total)
            returnNames.append(names[l])
            errorArray.append(list(tempArray))
        for x in range(0, len(errorArray)):
            appendData.append(errorArray[x])
        returnList = returnNames, returnTotals
        return list(returnList)
    except IndexError:
        return 4
# ========================================================================================================================== #


def saveOrder(saveData, filename):
    """
    Opens a file with name filename, and writes
    saveData to it.

    Args:

        saveData - the list of orders which will be
        written to the file.
        filename - a string value which gives the name
        of the file to be written to.

    Returns:
        Task Code 1 - If the task is complete successfully.
    """
    writeFile = csv.writer(open(filename, 'w', newline=''))
    writeFile.writerow(header)
    for i in range(0, len(saveData)):
        writeFile.writerow(saveData[i])
    return 1


def getOrders(writeData, filename):
    """
    Opens a file with name filename, and writes
    saveData to it.

    Args:

        saveData - the list of orders which will be
        written to the file.
        filename - a string value which gives the name
        of the file to be written to.

    Returns:
        Task Code 1 - If the task is complete successfully.
    """
    if os.path.isfile("pythoncsv.csv"):
        getFile = csv.reader(open(filename, 'r+', newline=''))
        for i in getFile:
            writeData.append(i)
        # Getting rid of header row so that we don't get a bunch of TypeErrors.
        writeData.pop(0)
        for i in writeData:
            i[2] = float(i[2])
            i[3] = float(i[3])
            i[4] = float(i[4])
            i[5] = float(i[5])
        print(writeData)
    else:
        # Creates file as above if statement tests whether it exists or not.
        getFile = csv.reader(open(filename, 'w', newline=''))
    return 1
# ========================================================================================================================== #


def printOrders(printData):
        # Purpose of first for loop is to ensure that longer names do not cause printing errors.
        space = 0
        tempString = "┃"
        for i in range(0, len(header)):
            tempString += spaceVal(header[i].title(), sizeDict[header[i].title()])
        print(printRow("┏", "┓", "━", "┳", header, sizeDict))
        print(tempString)
        print(printRow("┣", "┫", "━", "╋", header, sizeDict))
        tempString = ""
        for i in range(0, len(printData)):
            tempString = "┃"
            for x in range(0, len(printData[i])):
                tempString += spaceVal(printData[i][x], sizeDict[header[x].title()])
            print(tempString)
        print(printRow("┗", "┛", "━", "┻", header, sizeDict))
        print('\n')
        return 1
# ========================================================================================================================== #


def statOrders(statData):
    #try:
        statArray = [[0, 'Pizzas'], [0, 'Drinks'], [0, 'Desserts'], [0, 'Overall']]
        for i in range(0, len(statData)):
            statArray[0][0] += statData[i][2]
            statArray[1][0] += statData[i][3]
            statArray[2][0] += statData[i][4]
            statArray[3][0] += statData[i][5]
        space = 0
        tempString = "┃"
        for i in range(0, len(statHeader)):
            tempString += spaceVal(statHeader[i], statSizeDict[statHeader[i]])
        print(printRow("┏", "┓", "━", "┳", statHeader, statSizeDict))
        print(tempString)
        print(printRow("┣", "┫", "━", "╋", statHeader, statSizeDict))
        tempString = ""
        for i in range(0, len(statArray)):
            tempString = "┃"
            tempString = tempString + spaceVal(statArray[i][1], statSizeArray[0]) + spaceVal(str(statArray[i][0]), statSizeArray[1]) + spaceVal(str(int(100 * statArray[i][0] / statArray[3][0])) + '%', statSizeArray[2])
            print(tempString)
        print(printRow("┗", "┛", "━", "┻", statHeader, statSizeDict))
        print('\n')
        return 1
    #except (IndexError, TypeError):
     #   return 5
# ========================================================================================================================== #


def modifyOrder(modifyData, orderName, modifyValueType, newValue):
    try:
        for i in range(0, len(modifyData)):
            if(modifyData[i][0] == orderName):
                modifyData[i][posDict[modifyValueType]] = float(newValue)
                modifyData[i][5] = float(sum(modifyData[i][2:5]))
                return modifyData[i][5]
        return 4
    except (TypeError, IndexError):
        return 2
# ========================================================================================================================== #
# End of Asserts: Task Failed Succesfully
# ========================================================================================================================== #
```

And the specific function where the error occurs:

```py
def statOrders(statData):
    #try:
        statArray = [[0, 'Pizzas'], [0, 'Drinks'], [0, 'Desserts'], [0, 'Overall']]
        for i in range(0, len(statData)):
            statArray[0][0] += statData[i][2]
            statArray[1][0] += statData[i][3]
            statArray[2][0] += statData[i][4]
            statArray[3][0] += statData[i][5]
        space = 0
        tempString = "┃"
        for i in range(0, len(statHeader)):
            tempString += spaceVal(statHeader[i], statSizeDict[statHeader[i]])
        print(printRow("┏", "┓", "━", "┳", statHeader, statSizeDict))
        print(tempString)
        print(printRow("┣", "┫", "━", "╋", statHeader, statSizeDict))
        tempString = ""
        for i in range(0, len(statArray)):
            tempString = "┃"
            tempString = tempString + spaceVal(statArray[i][1], statSizeArray[0]) + spaceVal(str(statArray[i][0]), statSizeArray[1]) + spaceVal(str(int(100 * statArray[i][0] / statArray[3][0])) + '%', statSizeArray[2])
            print(tempString)
        print(printRow("┗", "┛", "━", "┻", statHeader, statSizeDict))
        print('\n')
        return 1
    #except (IndexError, TypeError):
     #   return 5
# ========================================================================================================================== #
```

Comment: be careful with the case `"% of Total"`  and `"% Of Total"`. dict keys are case-sensitive

Comment: Haha You are so right @PRMoureu , wow I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the quick reponse :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact
`"% of Total".title()` returns `% Of Total`.
This explains your error